Issue with Azure DevOps when git push
I tried to push a new project from scratch containing many files to Azure DevOps. Each time I did git push I got the following error:
Enumerating objects: 136, done.
Counting objects: 100% (136/136), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (125/125), done.
Writing objects: 100% (134/134), 270.82 KiB | 2.65 MiB/s, done.
Total 134 (delta 28), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 HTTP/2 stream 7 was reset
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

My environment: Windows 11 latest update, PowerShell 7.4.2 console with Git version (2.41.0.windows.1).
How do I fix this issue?

After some time, I found the solution in GitHub in this link.
I ran this command:
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1

Then
git push

All went well, then I put it back to HTTP/2
git config --global http.version HTTP/2

